# Avoid rewrite of path item that's the same as the RewriteBase in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to have modrewrite ignore the same string in a path that is not actually the base?

I am using this in my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /gallery/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
</IfModule>
```

Which works wonderfully. But I would like to be able to do something like

```
somesite.com/gallery/view/(username)/gallery/(gallery-name)
```

It rewrites the base beautifully, but also strips the second instance of /gallery/ in the path. Is there a way around this? Or should I modify my path structure to avoid repeating the rewritebase ?

Thanks,
TE

Comment: The mod-rewrite rules aren't stripping anything out of your path.

Comment: @TwstdElf: Is this your complete `.htaccess`? If not post the full code.